# Unity ios error build GameSparksWebSocket.h file not found GSExternal.m

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I got an error after building my game for iOS. I find the solution on the forum and google. But I never find the answer.

In my game I'm using Facebook SDK, and admob. But if I build my game, I got the error like this in the screenshot I attached here.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

1. The first step is to switch to the screenshot position in the left navigation bar in Xcode.as shown in the screenshot.

   [image]
2. Then enter the header file you gave the error in the bottom window position.as shown in the screenshot.

   [image]
3. If the left window filter shows the file, right click to find the file path.
4. Copy the path to Xcode's Build Setting->Header Search Paths，as shown in the screenshot.

   [image]